# How to find all documents from an array field compared against an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Person model with a field that is an array of values and my input is another array of values.

I need to find all people that have a matching value between the two arrays:

```
const Person1 = {
  inner: { field: ["1", "2", "3"] }
}

const Person2 = {
  inner: { field: ["2", "3"] }
}

const Person3 = {
  inner: { field: ["1"] }
}

const Person4 = {
  inner: { field: ["3"] }
}

const searchAgainst = ["1", "2"]
```

So given these 4 people with such values, when the Person model is searched with the `searchAgainst`, it should return `Person1, Person2, Person3`, so even if just one value of the `searchAgainst` is contained, it should be returned.

I have tried to do it like this:

```
const foundPeople = await Person.find({ inner: { field: { $in: searchAgainst }}});

const foundPeople = await Person.find({ "inner.field": { $in: searchAgainst }});
```

But it did not work, it doesnt return any found people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$elemMatch` operator. [From MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/):

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

So it seems to fulfill what you want with this:

```
Person.find({
  "inner.field": {
    $elemMatch: {
      $in: [
        "1",
        "2"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```